# Configuring Transaction via AOP in springboot app

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm used to configuring transaction management via AOP with XML files. They are something similar to:

```
<bean id="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="myTxManager">
    <tx:attributes>
       <tx:method name="get*,count*" read-only="true" />
       <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="com.company.my.exception.MyCompanyException" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="agencyServicePointCut" expression="execution(* com.company.my.project.server.spring.manager..*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="agencyServicePointCut" />
</aop:config>
```

By doing so, we have a standard way of developing, and every call to a method within the manager package enrolls a transaction. As we expose them via the services package, we are ensured everything runs under a transaction.

So the point is now I'm trying to achieve this behaviour programatically. I declared a BaseExceptionHandler

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class BaseExceptionHandler implements ErrorController {
...
    //Generic error
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<HttpResponse> internalServerErrorException(Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        return createHttpResponse (HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); 
    }
    private ResponseEntity<HttpResponse> createHttpResponse(HttpStatus httpStatus, String msg) {
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse(httoStatus.value(), httoStatus, httoStatus.getReasonPhrase(), msg);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, httpStatus);
    }
}
```

And every @RestController bean extends this BaseExceptionHandler (ideally, they extend their own ExceptionHandler that extends BaseExceptionHandler, so we decouple the handling of exceptions of the logic, getting far more clean code).

For example

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path = "/group")
public class GroupController extends BaseExceptionHandler {
}
```

In the very future, GroupController will extend GroupExceptionHandler, and GroupExceptionHandler will extend BaseExceptionHandler, so in BaseExceptionHandler I will attend exceptions such as AccessDeniedException, HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException or generic Exception, and GroupExceptionHandler only the ones regarding to Group.

So what I want to do is declare programatically (as is the standard on springboot, i think) something similar to the xml stated before:

- Every method under a com.company.my.project.controller is Transactional, which is similar to anotating it with @Transactional
- If it starts with get or count, it goes under read-only.
- I want it to rollback for any my.exception.MyCompanyException

What is the way of achieving it? Or am I doing something stupid? Having several RestControllers handling, at the very end, Exception.class is dangerous (or even, is it allowed?)
Guess I'm a little bit confused in how to handle this.

Edit:
We are writing a Controller and a Service per functionality, e.g GroupService and UserService, which are called from GroupController and UserController.
GroupService could throw their own exceptions (GroupAlreadyExistsException or UserMailNotExistsException for creating a group with a code that exists or updating a user by email) but also common exceptions (AccessDeniedException, TokenExpiredException (using JWT from auth0) or Exception). So does UserService. So each controller extends a BaseHandler (for handling those common exceptions) and then handles its own business exceptions. Our purpose is code cleanse, taking an inventory of every exception the app may throw and going back to frontend with a message as specific as possible (not just a generic internal_server_error but a maybe a bad_request, logging the error when its important, producing a message to a JMS, sending a mail... each exception may create a differente output, not just throw a 500 to a user).

So its something like:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class BaseExceptionHandler implements ErrorController {
    //Error generico
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<HttpResponse> internalServerErrorException(Exception e) {
        return createHttpResponse (HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    protected ResponseEntity<HttpResponse> creteHttpResponse(HttpStatus httpStatus, String msg) {
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse(httpStatus.value(), httpStatus, httpStatus.getReasonPhrase(), msg);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, httpStatus);
    }
}


@RestControllerAdvice
public class GruopExceptionHandler extends BaseExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(GroupAlreadyExistsException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<HttpResponse> grupoExistenteException(Exception e) {
        String msg = e.getMessage();
        String msgRespuesta = !StringUtils.isBlank(msg) ? msg : "Group already exists";
        return crearHttpResponse (HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, msgRespuesta); 
    }
}


@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path = "/group")
public class GroupController extends GruopExceptionHandler {

@PostMapping({ "/new" })
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_GROUP_CREATE')")
    public ResponseEntity<Group> newGroup(@RequestBody Group group) throws GroupAlreadyExistsException{
        Group newGroup = groupService.create(gruop.getCode(), group.getName());
        return new ResponseEntity<Group>(newGroup, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Comment: *And every @RestController bean extends this BaseExceptionHandler*?, why? You only need 1 exception handler for this. You shouldn't mix responsibilities in 1 class (remember the single responsibility principle). Work with the framework not against it. For your transactions I still would advice the annotations approach but if you really want you wold need to register the infrastructure beans for the namespace yourself. You can look at the code which ones that are (`TransactionInterceptor` with specific `TransactionAttributeSource` for one).

Comment: My approach is having a GroupController extending GroupExceptionHandler and a UserController extending UserExceptionHandler, but both handlers extend BaseExceptionHandler (any url mapping can handle common exceptions such as HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException).

Regarding tx, I was wondering on how doing so by AOP instead of using @Transaction on every single controller, as some developer may forget it (and annotating every controller looks boilerplate to me).
I read https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch10s06.html and guess declarative is better suited?

Comment: Making your controller the transactional boundary is a bad idea to start with, your service layer is the transactional boundary. Do you really want to rollback when rendering fails? And again you don't need all that exception handling stuff you need a single advice (which is why it is called advice as it is a cross-cutting concern). I also mentioned you will have to register all the beans the namespace registers but manually, it will require some work, but it will work. Also why are you reading that old reference guide? That is Spring 3.0 we are on 5.3 currently.

Comment: First of all, you're right, i wrote it incorrectly. The controllers wouldn't be the transactional ones, but the services. My mistake (on out monolithic apps, we name 'service' to the controllers and 'manager' to the services).  Why did I linked 3.0 instead of 5.3? Don't know lol. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.0/reference/html/data-access.html#tx-decl-vs-prog
Regarding the single advice, I was wondering having a controller advice per controller, so code is easy to read and mantain. The thing was avoiding writing the `@transactional`  annotation per `@service` bean.

Comment: An advice is a crosscutting concern, why would writing error handling code x times (x being the number of controllers you have) instead of 1 time be easier?

Comment: I've just edited the question adding some snippets, hope this clarifies our intention.

Comment: No it doesn't I still don't see how this benefits anything. YOu don't need the `@RestControllerAdvice` as it isn't really an advice. You can add `@ExceptionHandler` methods to controllers as well. So what you should have is an advice for the general exceptions and if you want a controller to handle something specific add a method to that but that isn't an advice as it isn't crosscutting.

Comment: I'm possibly wrong or misunderstanding how the advice works, then. My approach is getting the @exceptionhandlers methods on a different class (not the controller one), as I'm trying to decouple the handling and the business. On the other hand, I've identified several common exceptions to be handled by every controller. That's why I created a BaseHandler and then specific handlers for each controller, with everyhandler extending the basehandler. I'm trying to hand as much as possible and to avoid boilerplate. How should I go, then?

Comment: Ditch the `BaseHandler`. As stated an advice is a crosscutting concern and is applied to **every** controller. So you only need to define 1 advice for common exception handling, the controller shouldn't extend anything.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I'm doing right now (I will keep research on doing it programatically and try to find a way).

Created a transactions.xml file under src/main/resources/config and configured it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"
        > 

    
    <!-- Not defining transactionManager as using springboot default one (the name is important)-->
    <!-- Every @Service annotated class gets into the pointcut -->
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="serviceAnnotatedClass" expression="@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)" />
        <aop:advisor id="managerTx" advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceAnnotatedClass" order="20" />
    </aop:config>

  <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
      <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
      <tx:method name="load*" read-only="true" />
      <tx:method name="is*" read-only="true" />
      <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="com.company.my.project.exceptions.domain.MyBaseException" />
    </tx:attributes>
  </tx:advice>
</beans>
```

Every exception on the app must extend MyBaseException, of course.

Then, on the class annotated as @SpringBootApplication, add a line with @ImportResource heading to the xml we just created

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:config/transactions.xml")
public class ScoutingBeApplication {
}
```

Now, every class annotated as @Service will be under the txManager without needs of writing the @Transactional and everyone will use the same txAdvices (every method starting with load, find, get or is will be read-only, which is important for performance, and all of them will rollback if a checkexception extending MyBaseException is thrown.)
The point of doing so was standarizing the development process, avoiding as much boilerplate code as possible, taking an inventory of every single possible business exception (instead of reusing) and decoupling the handling of this exceptions and the business logic to make the code as clean as possible.

May this not be necessary for a project with a few services? Probably.

Comment: Why the specific exception? It will just rollback for any runtime exception already, why the additional exception in there? As mentioned you can do this with Java as well, just read the source code that is handling the `AopNamespace` and `TxNamespace` and find what is being registered with what classes and convert that into java.